# C# parameter count mismatch when trying to add AsyncCallback into BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have main form (PrenosForm) and I am trying to run Form2 asynchronously.

1. It works without callback delegate:

   ```
   this.BeginInvoke(cp, new object[] { datoteke, this.treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString(), this, efekt }, null); //works  1.
   ```
2. Doesn't work with callback delegate (parameter count mismatch):

   ```
    this.BeginInvoke(cp, new object[] { datoteke, this.treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString(), this, efekt }, new AsyncCallback(callBackDelegate), null); //doesn't work parameter count mismatch 2.
   ```
3. Works with callback delegate if I do it like this:

   ```
   cp.BeginInvoke(datoteke, this.treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString(), this, efekt, new AsyncCallback(callBackDelegate), null); //works  3.
   ```

My question is why does one way work and the other doesn't? I'm new at this. Would anyone be so kind as to answer my question and point out my mistakes?

```
 private delegate void copyDelegat(List<ListViewItem> datoteke, string path, PrenosForm forma, DragDropEffects efekt);
 private delegate void callBackDelegat(IAsyncResult a);

 public void doCopy(List<ListViewItem> datoteke, string path, PrenosForm forma, DragDropEffects efekt)
 {
     new Form2(datoteke, path, forma, efekt);
 }

 public void callBackFunc(IAsyncResult a)
 {
     AsyncResult res = a.AsyncState as AsyncResult;
     copyDelegat delegat = res.AsyncDelegate as copyDelegat;
     delegat.EndInvoke(a);
 }

public void kopiraj(List<ListViewItem> datoteke, DragDropEffects efekt)
{


 copyDelegat cp = new copyDelegat(doCopy);
 callBackDelegat callBackDelegate = new callBackDelegat(callBackFunc);
 this.BeginInvoke(cp, new object[] { datoteke, this.treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString(), this, efekt }, new AsyncCallback(callBackDelegate), null); //doesn't work parameter count missmatch 2.
 this.BeginInvoke(cp, new object[] { datoteke, this.treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString(), this, efekt }, null); //works  1.
 cp.BeginInvoke(datoteke, this.treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString(), this, efekt, new AsyncCallback(callBackDelegate), null); //works  3.

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because Control.BeginInvoke() has a completely different signature from SomeDelegate.BeginInvoke().  While their method names are the same, they are fundamentally different methods.  And fundamentally work differently at runtime, there is no comparison.

Control.BeginInvoke() takes a delegate and an object[].  Cast in stone.

private delegate SomeDelegate(mumble, foo, bar) automatically creates a SomeDelegate.BeginInvoke() method.  Whose signature takes those three arguments, *plus* two extra arguments, a callback and a state object.

A significant runtime difference is that Control.BeginInvoke() can call a delegate and if it bombs with an exception then the exception is raised on the UI thread.  A delegate's BeginInvoke() method doesn't do this, it re-raises the exception in the callback that calls EndInvoke().

Very confuzzling, I know, maybe they shouldn't have used the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this at all.
Showing multiple forms on different threads is an extremely bad idea and will end up causing lots of trouble.

Your second example doesn't work because [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) doesn't support a callback parameter.
Your code is interpreted as calling a delegate with three parameters; an array, and `AsyncCallback`, and `null`.
Since your method doesn't take such parameters, an exception is thrown.

Also, calling `Control.BeginInvoke` won't run a function in the background; it will run it on the UI thread when it next reaches the message loop.